# Special function $ 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \frac {z^{t(n)}}{t(n)!} $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, asymptotics, graphing-functions, almost-periodic-functions

Consider the “ special function “

$$ f(z) =  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \frac {z^{t(n)}}{t(n)!} $$

Where $t(n)$ means n th triangular number.

I assume it has No closed form despite resembling exp and theta functions.

Although I have no proofs or reliable computations it seems this function has Some intresting properties.

It seems to be almost periodic for $re(z) > 1$.
And that almost period is imaginary Just like exp !!

Also this function seems to grow like $exp( c z).$

Im fascinated. It reminds me of series multisection and substitution ( for computing integrals ).

Both on and off the real line this function behaves familiar and intresting.

But How about Some plots ( real or complex ) , proofs and ways of computing with them ?

For instance for real positive x :

$$Lim_x : f(x) \cdot exp(a x) = b $$

Does that hold and for What values $a,b$ ?
( Clearly a < 0 )

What is the value of the pseudoperiod ?

Does f(z) resemble exp rotated 3 times ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Some rough estimates indicate that $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Using $t_n=\frac{n (n+1)}{2}$

$$f(x) =  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \frac {x^{t_n}}{t_n!}=1+x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^{10}}{907200}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$ Considering $f(x)\,e^{ax}$ and developing as a Taylor series at $x=0$,we have
$$f(x)\,e^{ax}=1+(a+1) x+\frac 12\left({a^2}+2a\right) x^2+\frac{1}{6} \left(a^3+3 a^2+2\right)
   x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and then the result already given in a comment by Antonio Vargas $(a=-1,b=1$).

Comment: How do you know all those equations ( polynomials of a ) have a= -1 as one of Its solutions ??

Comment: Yes but is that not neccessary !? To complete the proof or such ? I mean , How does this Seattle the OP ? Or was it more a comment ?

Comment: +1 this resolved the question near $0$.